# Can we detect the existence of outliers using mean and median?

Tags: feature-selection, outliers

Suppose, I have a data set with eight features in my hand.

I have juxtaposed their means and medians row by row.

```
            f1       f2        f3        f4        f5        f6        f7        f8
mean      2.5000    0.1868    0.0148    0.2105    0.2088   79.6583    1.0604    0.0091
median    2.5000    0.1826    0.0001    0.0002    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
```

Can we tell anything about the existence of outliers from these information?

Comment: Not from just that. Not only does mean not equal to median not tell you there are outliers, mean $\approx$ median (or even exactly equal) doesn't tell you there aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any further knowledge I don't think so. You can construct a dataset that has a specific mean and variance by doing the following:

- Let the mean be $\mu$ and the median $m$ and the number of elements n.
- Put $n+1$ elements at m and $n$ at position $x$. We can find $x$ using $n,m,\mu$:
  $$\frac{nx+(n+1)m}{2n+1} = \mu \Rightarrow x = \frac{(2n+1)\mu-(n+1)m}{n}$$

We've created a dataset with no outliers (two huge clusters) for any given pair of $\mu, m$.

**Possible knowledge that could help**

Lots of times data is usually distributed more uniformly/continuously, not like my counterexample. In particular if the distribution is pretty centered (like a Gaussian) and there's an outlier, it will heavily influence the mean but not the median and this can be perceived.

However, if the distribution is not centered (like a geometric distribution) a big difference between mean and median may not mean much.

Comment: What kind of further knowledge can help in this regard?

Comment: updated answer to include your further knowledge question

Comment: Oh, I see!  The data is Normally distributed.

Comment: @Alan "it will heavily influence the mean but not the variance": I guess by variance you mean median here.

Comment: @anonymous If your data are normally distributed, you need not worry about outliers, but any substantial difference between mean and median implies that your sample is too small to allow serious analysis. To the point, what are your grounds for saying that? Have you tried e.g. normal probability plots?

Comment: As noted in the answer the difference between median and mean depends on the underlying distribution.  For symmetric distributions the mean is equat to the median while they can be very different for skewed distributions.  The definition of a univariate outlier depends on what you assume the underlying distribution is.  For the normal distribution observation extremely larger or extremely smaller than the mean are considered outliers.  Unfortunately if you use the sample mean you can have a masking effect since the sample mean is highly influenced by a single outlier.

Comment: For a normal distribution the mean is heavily influenced a single outlier while the median is not.  So comparing the sample median with the sample mean is way to detect a single outlier.. I differ with Nick Cox about the need to worry about outliers when the data is assumed to be normal. An outlier can exist as say an erroneous observaition.  Tge outlier detection technique devised by Frank Grubbs is a effective way to detect outliers when the data are assumed to be from a normal distribution. Dixon's ratio test is useful at detecting single outliers for a variety of symmetric distributions.